# PHP: Почему пропадают данные после json_decode

Tags: php, json

Ну, сам вопрос в заголовке.
Подробности:

Я делаю так

```
$url = "http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx";

$params["CType"] = 1;

$result = file_get_contents($url, true, stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method'  => 'GET',
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'content' => http_build_query($params)
                )
            )));
Print_r($result);
```

Выводит json, но кода я делаю это

```
$anec = json_decode($result);
print_r($anec);
```

Он ничего не выводит. 
Как исправить? Что я делаю не так? 
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а вы попробуйте var_dump сделать. того и гляди там bool => false написано

Comment: `json_decode` - Эта функция работает только со строками в кодировке `UTF-8`.А сайт этот возвращает другую кодировку, вот вам и тулит `NULL`.

Comment: А как исправить?

Comment: @And поэксперементирую, попробую исправить

Comment: Не получается, помогите пожалуйста. Пробовал utf8_encode($anec) Выводит ийроглифы

Comment: Вообще, этот сайт, очень странно работает. Когда пытаешься конвертнуть, он то норм отображает, то не отображает и так с проскоками, хотя конвертируются нормально. То есть когда делаешь конвертацию, он возвращает нормально массив, обновляешь `Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded`. То есть это уже на стороне их сервера проблемы какие-то с кодировками, хотя по заголовкам приходит `windows-1251`. Можете сами попробовать сделать `iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $json);` - по обновляйте страницу и увидите. Вообщем может и поправимо. Времени сейчас правда нет разбираться с этим.

Comment: Не помогло, но спасибо что хоть попробовали помочь. Буду искать другой сайт с анекдотами.

Comment: Говорю - же, оно помогает, только с некоторыми, там то синтаксические ошибки, то с кодировками, то с неправильными конвертациями ошибки летят. можете сами проверить через тот же `json_last_error_msg()`.

Answer (score 0):

Я проблему с json_decode не решил. Просто начал парсить анекдоты с другого сайта. 
Вот код

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');//подключаю библиотеку парсинга
include_once('func.php');//подключаю доп.функции

$site = file_get_html("https://www.anekdot.ru/random/anekdot/");//указываем сайт с аникдотом
$otvet = $site->find(".text");//ищем div class text

$anecdot = $otvet[0];//берём текст из div
//дальше уже вывожу анекдот туда куда нужно
```

Я решил, так, и у меня всё работает.

Нужно это было чтоб сделать автопостинг анекдотов в группе в вк.